# Having target_compile_definitions apply to static library that is linked in

Tags: c++, cmake

As part of the build process we produce two executables from our source exe1 and exe2. These executables link in a static library which has to have some extra code run in the case of exe2 so the static library has the following code (changed for brevity).

```
#ifdef _EXE2_

   Do certain stuff

#endif
```

now our CMakeLists.txt defines two targets exe1 and exe2, I tried the following change so that __EXE2_ would get defined only for exe2

```
target_compile_definitions(exe2 PUBLIC _EXE2_)
```

however it seems to me that the above line just adds this definition to exe2 and the static lib does not get that definition. Is there a way around this? or do i have to solve this with an exe configuration file. This is c++ code on linux if that helps in any way.

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscore followed by a uppercase letter are reserved by the C standard. Do not use such identifiers in your code.

Comment: If you need to compile the static library differently depending on what is linking against it, then you actually need two libraries (one library built with different flags is still two logical libraries).  I'd see if you can refactor your artifacts to isolate the `_EXE2_` specific stuff.

Comment: @StephenNewell, this thought did cross my mind. while I do realize that this is a compile time definition and possibly the suggestion you have suggested might me the way or I should possibly just redo this using some sort of application config. What I would like to learn from this is whether the linker provides any capability to inject this define somehow while linking.

Comment: @arunsun - No, the linker cannot help you.  Static libraries are collections of object files, meaning any macro definitions have already been applied to the source.  You need to apply the macros during compilation (technically during pre-processing), which happens much earlier.

Comment: Right you are. what i said about the linker makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would it? The exe depends on the library, not the other way around. Generally, a library has no relation to the modules that include it.

A library is also built once regardless of how many applications include it. That's the whole point of having a library.

If you want you can just add the definitions globally in your main CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_definitions(_EXE2_)
```

---

<sup>**Note** that identifiers beginning with an **underscore followed by an uppercase letter** are reserved and should not be used.</sup>

Comment: Makes sense. I was holding out hope that there might be some magic that the linker could possibly perform. (thanks for the pointer on the underscore, will change that).